# Boundedness for singular parabolic p-Laplace equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Local boundedness of singular parabolic $p$-Laplace equation

$$\partial_t u - \operatorname{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=0,\,1<p<2,$$

requires additional integrability assumption for the solution in the range $1<p\leq\frac{2n}{n+2}$. In particular, to prove a bound, one requires the solution $u$ to be in $L^r_\text{loc}(\Omega\times (0,T))$ for $r>\frac{n(2-p)}{p}$.

On the other hand, there are explicit examples

- In the range $1<p<\frac{2n}{n+1}$, there is an explicit example of the form $U(x,t)=C \left(\frac{(T-t)}{|x|^{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2-p}}$ valid for $x\neq 0$ and $0<t<T$, which is unbounded (near zero) in a larger range compared to the range $1<p\leq\frac{2n}{n+2}$. This example can be found in the following book in Section 11.5.4

*Vázquez, Juan Luis*, Smoothing and decay estimates for nonlinear diffusion equations. Equations of porous medium type, Oxford Lecture Series in Mathematics and its Applications 33. Oxford: Oxford University Press (ISBN 0-19-920297-4/hbk). xiii, 234 p. (2006). [ZBL1113.35004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1113.35004).

- In the range $\frac{2n}{n+1}<p<2$, there is another explicit example of the form $U(x,t)=C \left(\frac{(T+t)}{|x|^{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2-p}}$ valid for $x\neq 0$ which also appears to be unbounded near zero. This solution is remarked upon in the following article on page 37.

*Vázquez, Juan Luis*, [**The fractional (p)-Laplacian evolution equation in (\mathbb{R}^N) in the sublinear case**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00526-021-02005-6), Calc. Var. Partial Differ. Equ. 60, No. 4, Paper No. 140, 59 p. (2021). [ZBL1471.35312](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1471.35312).

**Question** I want to understand why the range of $p$ for these examples are larger than the critical range for local boundedness. To me, it feels like there is an ambiguity. Why do the examples make sense for $p>\frac{2n}{n+2}$ given the local boundedness theorem?